# Add an contextmenu item to inbox Outlook.MailItems with VSTO

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, outlook, vsto

I'm using VS2013 to create an Outlook addin for Outlook 2013.  Specifically I wish to add a "Call" item to the context menu that appears when you right click on a MailItem in your inbox.

Below is the code that I am starting with to get the currently selected MailItem.  I can verify I'm getting a handle to the right one by throwing out some debug MessageBoxes.  However, I cannot seem to access the MailItem contextmenu (to which I clearly want to do something like `cm.Items.Add(callMenuItem);`):

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   //Handle the event when the selected inbox MailItem changes:
   Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().SelectionChange += ThisAddIn_SelectionChange;
}

private void ThisAddIn_SelectionChange()
{
   //Get a handle to the current inbox MailItem:
   Outlook.MailItem mailItem = ((Outlook.MailItem)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1]);

   //Verify I've got the right one by showing a popup with the subject line:
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(mailItem.Subject);

   //Now I want to add an item to the context menu:
   // ??? Cannot find anything anywhere that shows
   //     shows how to add items to this contextmenu.
}
```

Anyway at all that I can get ahold of this would be a great start.  Eventually I'd also like to add this call button to the Outlook Home ribbon (next to "Reply") and to the mail popup Message ribbon ("next to "Reply").  Any details on adding this UI element in any of these places is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Sylverac Yes I tried this in combination with outlook and contextmenu and all permutations I could think of over teh past two days.  The same 5 or 6 top articles are what's returned and none of them are useful at all.

Comment: The link I provided literally answers your question. What didn't work about it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to handle the SelectionChange event if you need to customize context menus in Outlook. Instead, you need to use the Fluent UI. See [Customizing Context Menus in Office 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691832(v=office.14).aspx) for more information.

You can read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

I have noticed the following line of code:

```
//Handle the event when the selected inbox MailItem changes:
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().SelectionChange +=
```

You need to declare the source object at the global scope (class level) to keep the event fired all the time. Or the source object (Explorer) will be swiped by the garbage collector.